# Question about Fantasy Premier League API?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests, documentation

I've recently began learning about / working with APIs, and have always been taught to follow the documentation.

I've been trying to scrape the following page for all the stats on the players: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics but had little success.

I was told that the page was making an XHR request to https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/ to retrieve the stats.

My next question is... how would anyone even go about understanding how to retrieve data from such an API without documentation (as it was never an officially released API).  I see a lot of people talking about this API on reddit etc, but I'm puzzled at how they can know what/how to call.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Python package/script that does this. You can take a look how I did it and use it as is or modify it to suit your needs:

https://github.com/doughagey/FPL_to_csv

Comment: does the API have any backward compatibility when it is changed ? After it is changed, do they notify  users regarding it ?